# Could not execute editor for vi vim and gedit

Tags: git, vim

I am getting the following error message when I am trying to do

```
git rebase -i <commit no.>

Unknown option -w
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
Could not execute editor
```

From the other posts of stack overflow I tried out the following things:

1. changed default editor to vim, gave path as /usr/bin/vim
2. did the same thing for vi and gedit

loaded `~/.zshrc` using `source ~/.zshrc` but still getting the same issue.

What else can I try to get rid of this error.

Comment: Did you do `git config --global core.editor vim`?

Comment: It worked.!!!! Thanks. What does it do?

Comment: It will set the editor variable in your ~/.gitconfig file a.k.a your global git configuration file. git --help config

Comment: It's also worth noting you can do this via the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable too.  Git will prefer the `core.editor` config, then look for the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, and then fallback to `EDITOR`.

Answer (score 5):

The editor of your shell is set by

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

To set the editor in your `gitconfig`, one can use

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```